# getDistance() Android And AltBeacon

Tags: java, android, beacon

The signal frequency oscillates and the iBeacon library returns fluctuates distances
Example:

I am 1 meter from the beacon A;

And I'm 2 meters from the beacon B.

The library returns as if I were 1 meter from Beacon B and 5 from Beacon A.

I'm using Radius network device and Galaxy s8 mobile device with Android nougat.

Anyone know how to solve this?

https://github.com/VctrAndrade/BeaGO/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/victorandrade/beago/ui/MapaActivity.java

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it doesn't have anything to do with the code shown.  The problem is that the value returned by `getDistance()` is not correct for your test case and it reports the distance to b1 is greater than b2 whereas the real-world distance of b2 is greater than b1.  Do I understand correctly?

Comment: That's right, David.
The code snippet was for demonstration only

Comment: I think it is going to be very hard to answer this question without backing up to describe the use case.  What is the system supposed to do?   How have you  designed it to work?  What do you use distance estimates for?   How accurate do distance estimates need to be to accomplish your goal?   You may want to open a new question that covers these points, or at least edit your existing question above.

Comment: Hello David, sorry for the delay.
I was looking for a way out.

Edited

Comment: Are you seeing *consistent* results like you describe or are these *intermittent* readings?  In other words, does it always give you results like that or just sometimes?  Do you see the same results if you use an off the shelf beacon scanner like Locate?  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate

Comment: Hi David
The results are the same using the locate app.

The delivery of my academic work is next week, I think I have given up the tool.

I've tried it in every possible way.

Comment: Sorry I have not been able to help you get this working for you.